# Can't connect to Google Cloud SQL from within App Engine using SSL (in Django)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-sql

My app engine app is doing well, but I want to toggle the "only allow secure connections" option in the Cloud SQL configuration. When i do so, I can still connect remotely and in local development. However, my deployed app stops working with a 1045 error "access denied"

I cannot figure out where to store/upload the ssl certificates on the deployed app or how to call them from settings.py

Can someone please help?

Here is the relevant section of settings.py (redacted)

```
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):
    # Running on production App Engine, so use a Google Cloud SQL database.
       DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'HOST': '/cloudsql/<myappengineapp>:<mycloudsqlinstance>',
    'NAME': 'test',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '<mypassword>',
    'OPTIONS':

         <ssl goes in here?>

    }
}
```

else:
    # Running in development, but want to access the Google Cloud SQL instance

Comment: Is this relevant? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl?hl=en

Comment: I have read it many times; the answer does not seem to be there :(